# javascript access class method without initializing object

Tags: javascript

I have a class `foo`, can I access its public method `bar` with out initializing `fooObj`

```
var foo = function(){
   this.bar = function(){
       console.log("I am bar");
   }
}
```

I know I can access `bar` like

```
var fooObj = new foo();
fooObj.bar();
```

In other object oriented language like `jave`if I declare `bar` `static` I can access it with class name like `foo.bar`

Comment: Do not think in terms of "classes". Javascript doesn't have those. It's all just objects with properties.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `static` concept like `Java` but you can do something like

```
var foo = function(){
   // Constructor specific code
}

foo.bar = function(){
    console.log("I am bar");
}
```

This is how singleton will be defined in JavaScript

Comment: If you add it to prototype, it should work when you instantiate an object and call the method present in it.

Comment: @ Vigneswaran Marimuthu I didn't get what  I wanted as, deceze said Do not think in terms of "classes". Javascript doesn't have those. It's all just objects with properties.

Comment: @ozil What he meant is there is no concept of classes like in `Java`. If you see JavaScript you can see concepts like functions, objects and properties. Constructors are created using functions not classes in JavaScript. Though ES6 have classes concept but it's relatively new - http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2014/07/introduction-to-es6-classes-tutorial/